# Applying formatting coding style in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ Community Edition as my Java IDE. I am trying to set up my coding style preferences from `File -> Settings -> Preferences -> Code Style -> Java`. I applied my preferences, however, I want IntelliJ to create the javadocs templates for me when formatting. How can I do that?

I used other formatting tools like Jalopy that when formatted it creates the javadocs templates for you but not sure how to do that in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA does not have support for creating javadoc stubs when formatting. The lack of this functionality is intentional, because javadocs are only useful when they contain information written by a developer, and such an autogeneration feature will undoubtedly result in empty javadoc stubs with no information.

To generate a javadoc stub for a single method, type `/**` before a method, or press Alt-Enter and select "Add Javadoc" from the menu.

Comment: Aw so it doesn't create the empty javadoc stub? Do you know of any formatting plugin that will do that?

Comment: I don't, and I don't recommend you to use one. Please don't litter your code with useless doc stubs.

Comment: Oh hmm, even though I place information into my javadocs stubs?

Comment: If you do place information there, you do this by going over the methods one-by-one, and IntelliJ IDEA does support creating javadoc stubs for individual methods.